# What is the effect of a capacitor in series with a bridge rectifier?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, ac, single-phase

I kept a DC blocking (or AC coupling capacitor) in series with a single phase AC line followed by a bridge rectifier.

What I observed was that when I removed the capacitor (10nF), the voltage at the start of the bridge rectifier was equal to the line voltage. Whereas, when the capacitor is placed, the voltage at the start of the bridge rectifier was drastically reduced. As the value of capacitor is increased to uF range, the voltage at the start of rectifier also increased.

What is this phenomenon called and how does it happen?

Comment: Welcome! A full schematic is needed to answer your question. With respect to which node did you measure voltage?

Comment: Please at the very least post a schematic containing the cap, the bridge and values of the VAC and the load used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because a capacitor has impedance that is frequency dependent. The higher the capacitance, the lower the impedance, the higher the frequency the lower the impedance.

You can use an online calculator such as [this one](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/capacitor-impedance-calculator/) to find the impedance for a given capacitance and frequency.

For a 10 nF capacitor at 60 Hz it's around 265 k\$\Omega\$, so any load is going to cause a pretty good voltage drop across that impedance. As you increase the capacitance to something like 10 \$\mu\$F (1000 times as much) that impedance drops to 265 \$\Omega\$, so the voltage drop for a given load current will be 1000 times less.

So at a fixed frequency, adding a capacitor in series is like adding a resistor equal to the cap's impedance, and using higher capacitance is like using a lower resistance.

Using a series capacitor in a line powered circuit is sometimes done to drop voltage on purpose, it's a cheap way of getting lower voltage AC without the expense of a transformer. The downsides are that you lose isolation which can be a safety hazard, and capacitors don't tend to last anywhere near as long as transformers, so there a product life impact.